# Communications link error in Android project

Tags: android, mysql, jdbc

I have seen a lot of posts on this issue that deal with database permissions or firewall settings but I seem to be having a different problem.

I am getting an the error message "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server." when attempting to open a jdbc connection to a remote database from an Android application.

I know it is not an issue with permissions, firewall, or database availability because I am able to use the exact same java class to connect and make changes from a different application, and this functionality was working fine in a previous iteration of the code but is now causing problems. It is invoked the same way, the only difference is that in one project it is an Android application and in the other it is a regular Java app. If anybody has any ideas as to what the problem could be please let me know. The classes I am using are as follows:

```
public class DatabaseHandler{

private static String address;
private String username;
private String password;
private static Connection con;

public DatabaseHandler(String url, String un, String pw){
    address = "jdbc:mysql://[remote server IP]:3306/nfcgeo";
    username = un;
    password = pw;
}

public void openDB() throws Exception{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(address, username, password);
}
```

And in the MainMenu class for the android application:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    setupDatabaseConnection(context);
    if(!dbAvailable)
    {
        noDatabaseConnection(context);       

    }

public static void setupDatabaseConnection(Context _context)
{
    try
    {
    dbHandle = new DatabaseHandler("","root","rootpw");
    dbHandle.openDB();
    dbAvailable = true;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        dbAvailable = false;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Again, the DatabaseHandler class works perfectly if used outside of the android application, I only get the exception when it is called from the main menu. If anybody has any ideas please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the server has no permission alloted to a user named  u providing here as as username

so you need to run command on your database

1. Grant all on *.* to username identified by somepassword
   username -you will be using it to connect to the database
   password-you will be using it to connect to dB.
   so conection string will now be 
   jdbc:mysql://ip:3306/dbname,username,password
2. Flush privileges(check spelling)
3. If still does not work replace the bind-address:your ip to bind-address:0.0.0.0.
   this file is will be inside the mysql installation directory.